# Reduced size of dictionary elements when two lists combined into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have 2 lists that I combined their elements into a dictionary. Both lists have size of 20, and the created dictionary is almost always 13-15. The code is:

```
nodes = []
for x in range(1,21):
    nodes.append(str(random.randint(1,20)))
print(nodes)
```

Output:

```
['3', '6', '10', '12', '12', '10', '11', '17', '6', '19', '20', '19', '7', '16', '9', '13', '15', '9', '12', '5']
```

The rest of the code:

```
lines=[]

fp = open("work.txt") # open file on read mode
lines = fp.read().split("\n") # create a list containing all lines
fp.close() # close file
print(lines)
```

Output:

```
['5', '1', '7', '1', '1', '3', '12', '1', '1', '8', '7', '5', '12', '5', '5', '3', '7', '7', '13', '1', '']
```

To make a dictionary:

```
dictionary = dict(zip(nodes,lines))
print(dictionary)

{'3': '1', '6': '5', '10': '12', '12': '13', '10': '12', '11': '7', '17': '7', '6': '5', '19': '3', '20': '1', '19': '1', '17': '3', '16': '5', '9': '7'}
```

As you see, the size is got smaller to 14 when zipped. Do you know what is the reason and how can I fix it?

NOTE: I have to keep all the keys. The duplicates in the lists are on purpose.
NOTE2: The output should have the format above, the pairs of two numbers. (1,3) or (1:3) but not (1:3,4).

Comment: random returns the same values sometimes: your keys are not unique.

Comment: Yes, they are not unique by intention

Comment: You cant have two keys that arn't unique though, the first will be overwritten with the second.

Comment: maybe  you just want a list of `tuples` then. so do `tuples = list(zip(nodes,lines))`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a node,line dictionary, you need unique keys. Creating a dict from non-unique keys overwrites the first ones at some point.

If you *really* want non-unique indexes, just store your data in a list of tuples. You won't get quick access but that will work:

```
tuples = list(zip(nodes,lines))
```

Now if you want to *gather* the lines under the same node index, you can create a dictionary of *lists of lines* using for instance `defaultdict`:

```
import collections

d = collections.defaultdict(list)

for node,text in zip(nodes,lines):
    d[node].append(text)
```

so for each unique node, you get a list of associated lines.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works but I was quite trying to avoid from using tuples as I have to get all elements from each tuple to a file..

Comment: then try the defaultdict approach.

Comment: I have to get my output in "pairs of two numbers "format, therefore the defaultdict approach did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Because you can't have duplicate key names in a dictionary

```
>>> nodes = ['3', '6', '10', '12', '12', '10', '11', '17', '6', '19', '20', '19', '7', '16', '9', '13', '15', '9', '12', '5']

>>> lines = ['5', '1', '7', '1', '1', '3', '12', '1', '1', '8', '7', '5', '12', '5', '5', '3', '7', '7', '13', '1', '']

>>> dictionary = dict(zip(nodes,lines))

>>> len(dictionary.keys())
14
```

There are only 14 unique elemens in nodes, which are your dictionary keys

```
>>> len(set(nodes))
14
```

Comment: I have to keep the duplicated keys, how can I keep them?

Comment: Group the values together in a list

Answer (score 1):

Your "key" list has duplicate items. Dictionaries require unique keys, previously entered keys are overwritten.

You can group items in a list as follows

```
result = {}
for key, item in zip(x, y):
    if key in result:
        result[key].append(item)
    else:
        result[key] = [item]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't want a dictionary to begin with you want a list of tuples. Your code should instead be:

```
nodes = []
for x in range(1,21):
    nodes.append(str(random.randint(1,20)))
lines = []
fp = open("work.txt")
lines = fp.read().split("\n")
fp.close()
zipped = list(zip(nodes, lines))
```

This will give you a list of tuples with the first being the random number and the second being the read number and will not eliminate duplicates. It will instead print out in the format of [(3,5), (6,1), ...] rather than what it originally looked like though but should accomplish what I think you originally intended.

Comment: Is it possible that you can show me a small example?